# Careful proof of $2^{\sqrt{\log(n)}} = O(n^{\log(n)})$

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Many questions here ask specific questions about a big O comparison, but the answers feel like ideas of why it's obviously true, mentioning how to find our $n_0$ and $c$, or even just an evaluated limit, not formal proofs, and that's where I'm struggling. I know this above statement is true. My book would suggest taking logs of both sides, I get

$$ \text{log}(2^{\sqrt{\text{log}(n)}}) = \text{log}(2)\sqrt{\text{log}(n)}  = \text{log}(2)\sqrt{z} $$

$$ \text{log}(n^{\text{log}(n)}) = \text{log}(n)\text{log}(n) = \text{log}(n)^2 = z^2$$

Where I've identified $z = \text{log}(n)$ to make things a little clearer. If we take $z > 4$, then $z^2 > \text{log}(2) \sqrt{z}$, but $z = \text{log}(n) > 4 \Rightarrow n>10^4$.

This is what I know, but I'm having a hard time writing a proof that goes "Take $n_0 = \text{___}$ and $c = $___. Then for $n > n_0$, we have $$ 2^{\sqrt{\text{log}(n)}} < ... < cn^{\text{log}(n)}"$$

This is how these proofs should go, right? What can I do to make formulating them easier? Am I being too restrictive and formal?

Comment: Why not using expansion $(1+1)^{(\log (n))^{1/2}}$

Comment: It's good to pay attention to these things, for example it is not true that if $f = O(g)$ then $e^f = O(e^g)$, take $f = n \log 3$ and $g = n \log 2$ for a counterexample. So if you are taking logs to try to show things, you need some extra criterion before you can make the conclusion from the logged functions.

Comment: @Joppy Yes I've read and understood this as well. It's my understanding that when we do this, the goal is to use it in the inequalities involved in the proof, not to simply say 'well look at the exponential version, it works there so we're done'. In other words, I'm only using that log is strictly increasing. Does that work/make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general way is, after finding $n_0$ and $c$, to show the difference is increasing by taking derivatives. In this case, however, it is much simpler:

Take $n_0 = 10$ and $c = 1$. Then for $n > n_0$, note that $\log n > 1$. Hence:

$$2^{\sqrt{\log n}} < 2^{\log n} < n^{\log n}$$